# Calculate fractional exponent in for loop without power function

Tags: algorithm, math

My maths in this area is a bit shaky. Does anybody know how I can calculate a power such as 10^2.2 using no maths functions other than */-+ and a for loop? I don't have access to a maths library (and can't import/include it), but need to calculate these things. Hmm.. maybe I should just look how the math library does it.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164964/how-are-exponents-calculated. Related question. (Basically, you'd need to use a series expansion and round off at a desired level)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can compute logs & exponentials using only basic arithmetic with a Taylor (or Maclaurin) series expansion.  So, you should be able to take advantage of certain identities:

```
exp(ln(a)) = a
ln(a^b) = b*ln(a)
ln(1+x) = x - (x^2)/2 + (x^3)/3 - ... + ...
exp(x) = 1 + x + (x^2)/2 + ...
```

See what you can make of all of this...

Comment: If he doesn't have a math library, then he probably doesn't have log functions either

Comment: @Seth  That's why he needs the for loop. In other words, He does now.

Answer (score 3):

Given that:

```
a ^ (m / n) == nth_root(a) ^ m
```

Convert your [exponent to a fraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions), then compute the [nth root](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Nth_root#C), and then raise the result to the mth power.

(You'll have to write your own `pow` function.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFraction.html to get a very close approximation.

Answer (score 2):

Express the exponent as fraction and separate both parts (if the numbers get too big, you can use continued fraction expansion to get a good approximation):

2.2 = 22/10 = 11/5

10^2.2 = 10^(11/5) = (10^11)^(1/5)

The integer parts shouldn't be a problem (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Then you can calculate the root by one of the algorithms described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm