# How does Python calculate exponents?

Tags: python, python-2.7

To calculate exponents in Python, we use the `**` command. For example, we type `x**3` for the cube of x. How does Python evaluate such polynomials? Is that 3 flops used in this calculation? What about non-integer exponents? Say `x**2.3`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are exponents calculated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164964/how-are-exponents-calculated)

Comment: `x**3` would be just 2 operations (`t=x*x; t=t*x`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `**` operator translates to the `BINARY_POWER` opcode in the bytecode, which the interpreter then translates to the C-API [`PyNumber_Power` call](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/number.html#PyNumber_Power) with the 3rd argument set to None.

`PyNumber_Power` calls the [`nb_power` slot](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html?highlight=nb_power#PyNumberMethods) on the operands (see [`ternary_op`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/abstract.c#l1006)).

If both are integers, the [`int_pow` C function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/intobject.c#l728) succeeds and its result used.

If however `x` is an integer and you use `2.3` as the power, the integer power function raises an error and [`float_pow`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/floatobject.c#l807) is tried next. In that case, provided `x` is greater than 0, the C library `pow()` function is used on two float values, which on most architectures is then handled by the floating point support in the CPU.

Comment: But what about x not being an integer and the exponent y being integer? Is in this case also `float_pow` being used or there is a special method?

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus: that depends on the type of `x`. Python tries the left-hand operand first (by calling the `nb_power` slot, for Python types that's the [`__pow__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__pow__), and if that slot is missing or returns `NotImplemented` then [`y.__rpow__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rpow__) is tried. If the type you tried to use `**` is not a number, and doesn't implement `__pow__` then that'll probably just fail.