# How to calculate power of float

Tags: python

How can i calculate `10^0.3979400086720377` and then convert it in `int`, without using `math` library and `**`?

Comment: That seems like a strange requirement. Can you clarify why you can't use those two? Are other libraries also off-limits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/178074/3141234

Answer (score 1):

You can use built in pow() function.

```
result = pow(10, 0.3979400086720377)
print(int(result))
```